# Removing whitespaces in a string

Tags: c++, beginner, strings

I wrote this function to remove whitespaces in strings. Please help me improve it. I intended to use the function for a Big Integer ADT.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

void rs(char* str){
    int i(0);
    int j(0);


    while((*(str + i) = *(str + j++)) != '\0')
        if(*(str + i) != ' ')
            i++;
    return;
}


int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello World";
    char* result = strcpy((char*)malloc(str.length()+1), str.c_str());
    rs(result);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using C-String. C++ has its own string class conveniently called `std::string`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> char* result = strcpy((char*)malloc(str.length()+1), str.c_str());
> ```

This seems more suited for a C program than a C++ one. In fact, with C++11, you don't need to write your own function.

Behold: [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

**Note:**

> std::remove_if
>
> Removes all elements satisfying specific criteria from the range
>   [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new end of
>   the range.
>
> A call to remove is typically followed by a call to a container's
>   erase method, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the
>   physical size of the container to match its new logical size.

This is what you would do:

```
str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isspace), str.end());
```

I am not sure if this is the *safest* or *most efficient method*, but I think it's definitely an improvement to what you have done.

Comment: What are the scope operators for in `::isspace`

Comment: You are using `isspace` from the global namespace. Which in this case is from `<ctype.h>`

Comment: std::remove_if is not specific to C++11, though.